# How do enable colors in cmder for cmd.exe?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, conemu, cmder

I'm using Cmder on Windows 10. When I launch a regular console (`{cmd::Cmder}`) I get the colorful prompt as usual, like so:

[Regular styled cmder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoRud.png)

I've created a custom task to setup a Visual Studio 2019 environment to build my applications with `cl` and `ml`:

```
<key name="Task3" modified="2020-04-03 21:10:59" build="191012">
    <value name="Name" type="string" data="{VS19 x86}"/>
    <value name="Hotkey" type="dword" data="00000000"/>
    <value name="GuiArgs" type="string" data=' /icon "%CMDER_ROOT%\icons\cmder.ico"'/>
    <value name="Cmd1" type="string" data='cmd /k ""%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" "'/>
    <value name="Active" type="long" data="0"/>
    <value name="Count" type="long" data="2"/>
    <value name="Flags" type="dword" data="00000004"/>
    <value name="Cmd2" type="string" data='cmd /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"" x86 -new_console:t:"VS19 x86"'/>
</key>
```

When I launch a new `{VS19 x86}` console it sets up the environment correctly but now I've got a standard prompt with no colors:

[Image of unstyled cmder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I95U.png)

How do I enable the colors?